# Break from for loop

Tags: python, breakpoints

Here is my code:

```
def detLoser(frag, a):
    word = frag + a

    if word in wordlist:
        lost = True
    else:
        for words in wordlist:
            if words[:len(word) == word:
                return #I want this to break out.

            else:   
                lost = True
```

Where I have a return, I've tried putting in both return and break and both give me errors.  Both give me the following error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax.  Any Ideas?  What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax -- same as with break.

Comment: `return` and `break` will both work as it's a loop inside a function.

Comment: Please provide the **actual** error message you're getting.

Comment: What is this code _supposed_ to do? Do you need to return `lost`? `lost` is never set to `False` anywhere

Comment: S. Lott: Look two comments up.

Gnibbler: I've since rewrote it to return lost.  This is a code fragment.  It assumes that the player hasn't lost until it is set to true.  The code evaluates loosing conditions.

Comment: @NoahClark: Look two comments up.  Please provide the **actual** error message.  Not your version of it.  But the actual copy-and-paste actual error message.  The **actual** error message.  Please.  It helps others who have the same problem to provide the **actual** message.  Also, please **update** your question to include the **actual** message, copied and pasted.  Please.

Comment: I did copy and paste it. "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Comment: @NoahClark: When I get a Syntax Error, I usually see quite a bit more than four words.  Please include the entire **actual** error message.  All four lines of it.

Comment: S. Lott I use a special version of python that is designed to frustrate you to no end ;)

Comment: @NoahClark: Well, I don't seem to have your problem.  Without **details** other people -- like me -- will pass by your question.  You might be able to help these people by including the actual error message they'll actually see.  That would be helpful to others.  Of course, you don't have to return the favor of getting and giving help.  You're free to get help without offering help to others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've omitted the `]` from the list slice. But what is the code trying to achieve, anyway?

```
foo[ : len( foo ) ] == foo
```

always!

I assume this isn't the complete code -- if so, where is `wordlist` defined? (is it a list? -- it's much faster to test containment for a set.)

Comment: Yeah, wordlist is a list. What do you mean test containment for a set?

Comment: python set is a hashtable, so lookup probably is not as slow as O(log n)

Comment: @unbeli: true that. I was thinking binary search... should be amortized O(1) I thin?

Answer (score 2):

```
def detLoser(frag, a):

    word = frag + a

    if word in wordlist:
        lost = True
    else:
        for words in wordlist:
            if word.startswith(words):
                return #I want this to break out.
            else:   
                lost = True
```

you can probably rewrite the for loop using `any` or `all` eg. ( you should use a set instead of a list for wordlist though)

```
def detLoser(frag, a):
    word = frag + a
    return word in wordlist or any(w.startswith(word) for w in wordlist)
```